# Jquery export options work in Chrome and Firefox but not IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a page that displays an html table full of data pulled from an sql database. Attached to that table is an option to export to several different formats, I got the code here: (http://w3lessons.info/2015/07/13/export-html-table-to-excel-csv-json-pdf-png-using-jquery/).

Everything works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but not IE (8, 9, or 10). When I try to do the export in IE, IE decides to open another tab and I get a "page cannot be displayed error". I don't know why IE has this confusion but Chrome and Firefox don't.

Summary.asp:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<title></title>
<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link href="css/blog-post.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
<script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<%
dim epstartdate
    epstartdate = request.form("datepickstart")
    dim ependdate
    ependdate = request.form("datepickend")
%>

<%
    dim dbconn
    set dbconn = server.createobject("adodb.connection")
    dbconn.open "dsn=*****;uid=*****;pwd=*****;"
    'if dbconn.errors.count > 0 then
    '   response.write "connection erros<br>"
    '   for each objerr in dbconn.errors
    '       response.write objerr.source & "<br>"
    '       response.write objerr.description & "<br>"
    '   next
    'end if
    dim epsummrecset
    dim sqlstr
    sqlstr = "*****My SQL String*****"
    set epsummrecset = server.createobject("adodb.recordset")
    epsummrecset.open sqlstr, dbconn
%>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-8">
<p class="lead">
<div class="row">
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
<h3 class="panel-title">
Summary From:
<% =epstartdate %>
to:
<% =ependdate %>
</h3>
<div class="pull-right">
<button class="btn btn-danger toggle" data-toggle="exportTable"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i>Export Options</button>
</div>
</div>
<div class="panel-body" id="exportTable" style="display:none">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-2">
<div class="list-group border-bottom">
<a href="#" class="list-group-item" onClick ="$('#epsummary').tableExport({type:'xml',escape:'false'});"><img src='http://demos.w3lessons.info/assets/images/icons/xml.png' width="24"/> XML</a>
<a href="#" class="list-group-item" onClick ="$('#epsummary').tableExport({type:'sql'});"><img src='http://demos.w3lessons.info/assets/images/icons/sql.png' width="24"/> SQL</a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
<div class="list-group border-bottom">
<a href="#" class="list-group-item" onClick ="$('#epsummary').tableExport({type:'csv',escape:'false'});"><img src='http://demos.w3lessons.info/assets/images/icons/csv.png' width="24"/> CSV</a>
<a href="#" class="list-group-item" onClick ="$('#epsummary').tableExport({type:'txt',escape:'false'});"><img src='http://demos.w3lessons.info/assets/images/icons/txt.png' width="24"/> TXT</a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="list-group border-bottom">
<a href="#" class="list-group-item" onClick ="$('#epsummary').tableExport({type:'excel',escape:'false'});"><img src='http://demos.w3lessons.info/assets/images/icons/xls.png' width="24"/> XLS</a>
<a href="#" class="list-group-item" onClick ="$('#epsummary').tableExport({type:'doc',escape:'false'});"><img src='http://demos.w3lessons.info/assets/images/icons/word.png' width="24"/> Word</a>
<a href="#" class="list-group-item" onClick ="$('#epsummary').tableExport({type:'powerpoint',escape:'false'});"><img src='http://demos.w3lessons.info/assets/images/icons/ppt.png' width="24"/> PowerPoint</a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
<div class="list-group border-bottom">
<a href="#" class="list-group-item" onClick ="$('#epsummary').tableExport({type:'png',escape:'false'});"><img src='http://demos.w3lessons.info/assets/images/icons/png.png' width="24"/> PNG</a>
<a href="#" class="list-group-item" onClick ="$('#epsummary').tableExport({type:'pdf',escape:'false'});"><img src='http://demos.w3lessons.info/assets/images/icons/pdf.png' width="24"/> PDF</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="panel-body panel-body-table">
    <table id="epsummary" class="table table-striped">
        <tr>
            <td>Machine Name</td>
            <td>Start Time (E.T.)</td>
            <td>End Time (E.T.)</td>
            <td>Status</td>
        </tr>
<%
    while not epsummrecset.eof
        response.write "<tr><td align=center>"
        response.write epsummrecset("si_host") &  "</td><td align=center>"
        response.write "<a href=epdetails.asp?epsummid=" 
        response.write epsummrecset("si_id")
        'make the link red if the status is not success
        if epsummrecset("si_status_id") = 1 then
            response.write "><font color=blue><strong>"
        else
            response.write "><font color=red><strong>"
        end if
        response.write trim(epsummrecset("si_start_ts")) & "<strong></font></a></td><td align=center>"
        response.write trim(epsummrecset("si_end_ts")) & "</td><td align=center>"
        response.write trim(epsummrecset("st_status_description")) & "</td>"
        epsummrecset.movenext
    wend
    epsummrecset.close
    dbconn.close
%>
</table>
</div>
</div>
<div id="down_update"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://demos.w3lessons.info/assets/js/tableexport/tableExport.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://demos.w3lessons.info/assets/js/tableexport/jquery.base64.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://demos.w3lessons.info/assets/js/tableexport/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://demos.w3lessons.info/assets/js/tableexport/jspdf/libs/sprintf.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://demos.w3lessons.info/assets/js/tableexport/jspdf/jspdf.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://demos.w3lessons.info/assets/js/tableexport/jspdf/libs/base64.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){   
    /* TOGGLE FUNCTION */
    $(".toggle").on("click",function(){
        var elm = $("#"+$(this).data("toggle"));
        if(elm.is(":visible"))
            elm.addClass("hidden").removeClass("show");
        else
            elm.addClass("show").removeClass("hidden");
        return false;
        });
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function(){
jQuery('.downloadnow').on("click",function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
    var semail = jQuery("#downloademail").val();
    var pageID = jQuery("#downloadID").val();
    if(semail == '')
    {
        alert('Enter Email');
        return false;
    }
    jQuery(".downloadnow").html('Loading..');
    var str = "sub_email="+semail+"&pageID="+pageID;
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://demos.w3lessons.info/download",
        data: str,
        cache: false,
        success: function(htmld){
            jQuery('#down_update').html(htmld);
            jQuery(".downloadnow").html('Download Now');
        }
    });
    }); 
});  
</script>

<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-27820211-3', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The plugin used may be: tableExport.jquery.plugin? If so see the issue : https://github.com/kayalshri/tableExport.jquery.plugin/issues/47

Comment: Hmm. Having a poke about in the source code for that plugin I see this: window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-'+defaults.type+';filename=exportData.doc;' + base64data); That's for a spreadsheet but he probably uses the same tactic for other file types. Most likely this is what is causing the problem in IE < 11.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is an issue with plugin code the window.open() does not work as expected on IE, some one fixed that, you can try it:
https://github.com/kayalshri/tableExport.jquery.plugin/pull/28/files

Comment: Thank you very much for the link. It seems I am one step closer... IE isn't tossing my into random open tabs any longer.

However, now IE just sits there with the page status spinning like IE is working on it. I'm not extremely comfortable with jquery quite yet, could you help point out where I should be adding this code/removing old code?